# Dynamically create periodic tasks or one time tasks - django celery beat

Tags: django, django-views, celery

We have multiple scripts written in different lang ( Python, shell, golang ) and so on.
I am trying to create a centralized application, where any user can create periodic tasks or one time tasks using django/celery.

Basically the idea is

```
user1 -> python test.py arg
user2 -> ./test.sh arg1 arg2
```

The idea is not to pre defined tasks and dynamically create tasks.
is it possible ??
any lead or blog should be helpful.

Comment: Doesn't cron fit your use case? You can also look at cron libraries implemented in different languages to handle dynamic creation of tasks. I don't think celery beat is a better fit for your use case.